# ViewPagerIndicator: change page count

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

We will dynamically add/remove pages and I would like to know if it would work with the infamous [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)

So far I haven't even tried but I want to check in advance if it would work.
Do you see any problem with it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try it before asking a programming-related question. Imagine if everybody was asking those kind of question *priori*...

Answer (score 0):

Works like a charm!

As long as the page count is in expected boundaries (*0 < count < ?*),

when adding / removing a page, calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` 
**on both the indicator and the adapter** does the trick.